# SwiftUI trigger function when model updates inside @Published property

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swift5, combine

I am getting an array from a Firestore table. Obviously is in real time so any newly added document or modifications to an existing document are reflected in the view. This works for simple properties like strings and numbers but I need to display and refresh other data too.

I'm storing the coordinates also and if the coordinates change I need to call `geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation()` in order to get the Placemark out of this location and display the address as a string. For this I have created a service called `PlacemarkService (code provided below).`

The issue is this. Whenever a model is modified the data comes through `PackagesViewModel` which has a `@Published var results = [Package]()` This is modified on the fly by Firestore (codable). Then, any changes caused to array this will cause the `List` inside `PackagesView` to be refreshed and this will cause a new instance of `PackageView(packageService: PackageService(package: package))` to be created and since the `PackageService` is passed as a param here a new instance of `PackageService` will be created. Finally this will trigger the init() inside this service to be called.

`@Published var results = [Package]() -> List -> PackageView(packageService: PackageService(package: package)) -> init()`

So now if I follow this flow and I trigger `getPlacemarks()` inside init everything works (most of the time) and if the package model changes this function will be called on init and will reverseGeocodeLocation of the modified location. But there is a big problem here and here is why. I can not put this logic on init since I can not geocode hundreds of locations inside a for loop. I have multiple packages displayed on a list and MapKit won't allow this.

So obviously this logic needs to be triggered after the `PackageView` is shown, so when one of those packages is selected.

If I call `packageService.getPlacemarks()` when PackageView appears this works fine the first time but... onAppear won't be triggered when `@Published var results = [Package]()` is updated.

So finally the question is:

***Where to call `packageService.getPlacemarks()` so it gets called whenever a `Package` inside `@Published var results = [Package]` is updated***

but not on init of PlacemarkService for the reason I explained above.

Sorry for the long explanation, I am just trying to be clear.

```
class PackageService: ObservableObject {
    var package: Package
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    
    @Published var sourcePlacemarkService = PlacemarkService()
    @Published var destinationPlacemarkService = PlacemarkService()
    
    var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
    
    init(package: Package) {
        self.package = package
        startListening()
    }
    
    func startListening() {
        // Listen to placemark changes.
        cancellable = Publishers.CombineLatest(sourcePlacemarkService.$placemark, destinationPlacemarkService.$placemark).sink(receiveValue: {_ in
            
            // Publish changes manually to the view.
            self.objectWillChange.send()
        })
    }
    
    // Get placemarks from locations
    func getPlacemarks() {
        sourcePlacemarkService.reverseGeocodeLocation(location: package.source.toCLLocation)
        destinationPlacemarkService.reverseGeocodeLocation(location: package.destination.toCLLocation)
    }
}

class PackagesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var results = [Package]()
    
    func load() {
        query.addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in 
            // updates results array when a document is modified.
        }
    }
}


struct PackagesView: View {
    @StateObject var packagessViewModel = PackagesViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        List(packagessViewModel.results, id: \.self) { package in
            NavigationLink(destination: PackageView(packageService: PackageService(package: package))) {
                Text(package.title)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PackageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var packageService: PackageService

    func onAppear() {
        packageService.getPlacemarks()
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        // show the address from placemark after it is geocoded.
        VStack {
            Text(packageService.sourcePlacemarkService.placemark.title)
            Text(packageService.destinationPlacemarkService.placemark.title)
        }
        .onAppear(perform: onAppear)
    }
}

class PlacemarkService: ObservableObject {
    @Published var placemark: CLPlacemark?
    
    init(placemark: CLPlacemark? = nil) {
        self.placemark = placemark
    }
    
    func reverseGeocodeLocation(location: CLLocation?) {
        if let location = location {
            geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location, completionHandler: { (placemark, error) in
                // some code here
                self.placemark = placemark
            })
        }
    }
}

struct Package: Identifiable, Codable {
    @DocumentID var id: String?
    var documentReference: DocumentReference
    
    var uid: String
    var title: String
    var description: String
    var source, destination: GeoPoint
    var amount: Double
    
    var createdAt: Timestamp = Timestamp()
    var paid: Bool = false
}
```

Comment: put it in the `didSet` for `results`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly - simplifying this code. Most of this code is unnecessary to reproduce the problem, and can't even be compiled. The code below is **not** the working code, but rather what we have to start and change later:

#### ContentView

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            PackagesView()
        }
    }
}
```

#### PackageService

```
class PackageService: ObservableObject {
    let package: Package

    init(package: Package) {
        self.package = package
    }

    // Get placemarks from locations
    func getPlacemarks() {
        print("getPlacements called")
    }
}
```

#### PackagesViewModel

```
class PackagesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var results = [Package]()
}
```

#### PackagesView

```
struct PackagesView: View {
    @StateObject var packagesViewModel = PackagesViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add new package") {
                let number = packagesViewModel.results.count + 1
                let new = Package(title: "title \(number)", description: "description \(number)")
                packagesViewModel.results.append(new)
            }

            Button("Change random title") {
                guard let randomIndex = packagesViewModel.results.indices.randomElement() else {
                    return
                }

                packagesViewModel.results[randomIndex].title = "new title (\(Int.random(in: 1 ... 100)))"
            }

            List(packagesViewModel.results, id: \.self) { package in
                NavigationLink(destination: PackageView(packageService: PackageService(package: package))) {
                    Text(package.title)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### PackageView

```
struct PackageView: View {
    @ObservedObject var packageService: PackageService

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Title: \(packageService.package.title)")

            Text("Description: \(packageService.package.description)")
        }
    }
}
```

#### Package

```
struct Package: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var title: String
    let description: String
}
```

---

Now, solving the problem. I fixed this issue by detecting the `results` changing with [`onChange(of:perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/onchange(of:perform:)). However, from here there is no way to access the `PackageService`s used in the view body.

To prevent this issue, the `PackageService`s are actually stored in `PackagesViewModel`, which logically makes more sense for the data flow. Now with `PackageService` also being a `struct` so the `@Published` works on the array for `results`, this now works.

See the code below:

#### PackageService (updated)

```
struct PackageService: Hashable {
    var package: Package

    init(package: Package) {
        self.package = package
    }

    // Get placemarks from locations
    mutating func getPlacemarks() {
        print("getPlacements called")

        // This function is mutating, feel free to set any properties in here
    }
}
```

#### PackagesViewModel (updated)

```
class PackagesViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var results = [PackageService]()
}
```

#### PackagesView (updated)

```
struct PackagesView: View {
    @StateObject var packagesViewModel = PackagesViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Add new package") {
                let number = packagesViewModel.results.count + 1
                let new = Package(title: "title \(number)", description: "description \(number)")
                packagesViewModel.results.append(PackageService(package: new))
            }

            Button("Change random title") {
                guard let randomIndex = packagesViewModel.results.indices.randomElement() else {
                    return
                }

                let newTitle = "new title (\(Int.random(in: 1 ... 100)))"
                packagesViewModel.results[randomIndex].package.title = newTitle
            }

            List($packagesViewModel.results, id: \.self) { $packageService in
                NavigationLink(destination: PackageView(packageService: $packageService)) {
                    Text(packageService.package.title)
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: packagesViewModel.results) { _ in
            for packageService in $packagesViewModel.results {
                packageService.wrappedValue.getPlacemarks()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### PackageView (updated)

```
struct PackageView: View {
    @Binding var packageService: PackageService

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Title: \(packageService.package.title)")

            Text("Description: \(packageService.package.description)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `.onChange(of: packagesViewModel.results) { _ in
            for packageService in $packagesViewModel.results {
                packageService.wrappedValue.getPlacemarks()
            }
        }` this is an async call and this means that for every change this will be triggered multiple times. Is this the best place to put this. Shouldn't this be in the PackageView?

Comment: In the question: ` I can not geocode hundreds of locations inside a for loop. I have multiple packages displayed on a list and MapKit won't allow this.`

Comment: @M1X It depends what you are looking for. If you are changing `package` in `PackageService` which triggers an update in `PackagesView`, it may call `onChange` multiple times. However, this is expected since the view is correctly updated when a package is changed. What you may want to do is a condition in the `if` in the `onChange` to only trigger when a specific property actually changes.

Comment: @M1X You can do `.onChange(of: packagesViewModel.results) { [old = packagesViewModel.results] new in ... }` and only allow the call to `getPlacemarks()` if certain properties have changed

Comment: `.onChange(of: packageService) { _ in
            $packageService.wrappedValue.refreshPlacemarks()
        }` What about detecting the change in the PackageView.. I tried this it compiles but the view does not get refreshed

Comment: @M1X `packageService` doesn't change because it is an instance. But the property wrappers observe it. `onChange` looks for a change in the _value_, which doesn't happen when mutating properties of an object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239561/discussion-between-george-and-m1x).

Answer (score 2):

I think that easiest way to solve your problem is initially call `getPlacemarks` in `onAppear`, and re-calling it with `onChange`, like this:

```
VStack {
    Text(packageService.sourcePlacemarkService.placemark.title)
    Text(packageService.destinationPlacemarkService.placemark.title)
}
.onChange(of: packageService.package.id) { _ in
    packageService.getPlacemarks()
}
.onAppear {
    packageService.getPlacemarks()
}
```

Depending on which fields of your package struct change, you may need make it `Equtable` and pass the whole object instead of `id`.

Comment: I get an error: `Value of type 'Package' has no member 'objectWillChange'`. And this will refresh the view or will update the data? because updating the data is not the issue it already works but as I mentioned I need to trigger `sourcePlacemarkService.reverseGeocodeLocation(location: package.source.toCLLocation)` when `package.source` changes.

Comment: @M1X I didn't read your question carefully the first time, please see the updated answer.

Comment: I new instance of PlaceMark service is created but getPlacemarks() is not called